# "Fortran runtime error: End of file" problem when creating a linked list with pointer (READ in DO loop)

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I am creating a linked list from the input file. Each node in the linked list includes the information in each block of the input. 
When I try to get value from input file, I assigned multiple lines (4 lines each time) into a 1D array "tmp". I think the DO-loop I used in the  "input:DO" loop is wrong. But I do not know how to solve.

I use gfortran to compile and no mistake come out for compiling.
I have tried WRITE for testing in the "input:DO" loop for testing. The result shows that I can open the input file successfully.

```
PROGRAM read
  IMPLICIT NONE

  INTEGER,PARAMETER :: nat=4
  character(len=20) :: filename
  !Derived types to store atom data 
   TYPE :: atom
     CHARACTER(LEN=2) :: atom_name
     REAL, DIMENSION(3) :: coord      
   END TYPE atom
  !The array info stores info of all atom in one time step
  type :: atom_seq
    type(atom),dimension(nat):: info
    type(atom_seq),pointer :: p
  end type atom_seq
  TYPE (atom_seq), POINTER :: head 
  TYPE (atom_seq), POINTER :: tail 
  type(atom), dimension(nat) :: temp

  ! Declare variable
  INTEGER :: istat
  INTEGER :: i=0, n=0

  ! Open input data file
  WRITE(*,*) 'ENTER the file name with the data to be read: '
  READ(*,'(A20)') filename
  NULLIFY(head)
  OPEN( UNIT=9, FILE=TRIM(filename), STATUS="OLD", ACTION="READ", IOSTAT=istat)
  ! Was the open successful
  fileopen: IF (istat == 0) THEN
    input: DO
      !WRITE(*,*) "OPEN done " ! for testing
      READ(9,*)                ! <--when run, error is in this line
      READ(9,*)
      DO i = 1, nat
        READ(9,*,IOSTAT=istat) temp(i)%atom_name, temp(i)%coord(1), temp(i)%coord(2), temp(i)%coord(3)
      ENDDO

      IF (istat /= 0) EXIT
      n = n + 1  ! Bump count
      IF (.NOT. ASSOCIATED(head) ) THEN  ! No values in list
        ALLOCATE(head, STAT=istat)       ! Allocate new value
        tail => head                     ! Tail points to new value  
        NULLIFY(tail%p)                  ! Nullify p in new value
        DO i = 1, nat  ! Store number
          tail%info(i)%atom_name = temp(i)%atom_name
          tail%info(i)%coord(1) = temp(i)%coord(1) 
          tail%info(i)%coord(2) = temp(i)%coord(2)
          tail%info(i)%coord(3) = temp(i)%coord(3)
        ENDDO

      ELSE     ! Values already in list
        ALLOCATE(tail%p, STAT=istat) ! Allocate new value
        tail => tail%p
        NULLIFY(tail%p)
        DO i = 1, nat  ! Store number
          tail%info(i)%atom_name = temp(i)%atom_name
          tail%info(i)%coord(1) = temp(i)%coord(1) 
          tail%info(i)%coord(2) = temp(i)%coord(2)
          tail%info(i)%coord(3) = temp(i)%coord(3)
        ENDDO
      END IF
    END DO input
  ELSE fileopen
    WRITE(*,1030) istat
    1030 FORMAT ('File open failed --status =  ', I6)
  END IF fileopen
END PROGRAM read
```

The input file: inp

```
     4
 Particles:1_0
  O         0.8050005000        0.7000000000        3.2350000000
  H         1.4750005000        1.2800000000        2.8650000000
  H         0.8550005000       -0.0900000000        2.7150000000
  O         0.4050005000        0.7500000000       -4.1350000000
     4
 Particles:1_5
  O         0.8799478358        0.6383317306        3.1569568025
  H         1.4046592860        1.2232485826        2.4978364665
  H         1.1472783731       -0.2687458123        3.0229092093
  O         0.5392992531        0.6047144782       -4.0811918365
     4
 Particles:1_10
  O        -3.8021765454        3.1600783692       -4.5455655916
  H        -4.5320715486        3.0937504111        4.9514896261
  H        -3.5088238380        4.0613340230       -4.5394597924
  O        -3.3469012765       -0.7064128847        1.2465212113
```

and the error is

```
hg@xi /home/hg/pole $ ./read 
 ENTER the file name with the data to be read: 
inp
At line XXX of file read.f95 (unit = 9, file = 'inp')
Fortran runtime error: End of file

Error termination. Backtrace:
#0  0x7f1c1fdbb31a
#1  0x7f1c1fdbbec5
#2  0x7f1c1fdbc68d
#3  0x7f1c1ff32a33
#4  0x7f1c1ff364b7
#5  0x7f1c1ff365b8
#6  0x5566d3dc9daf
#7  0x5566d3dca9ed
#8  0x7f1c1f9d0b96
#9  0x5566d3dc9a79
#10  0xffffffffffffffff
```

I hope to fix the problem. If my idea is wrong, please give some suggestions to design a better data structure to save data in the input (The input file may have thousands of blocks, instead of 3. It is big and the number of blocks is unknown before running the code. )

Comment: I think that you need to test the status of the first read during the loop as well. (read(9,*))  Otherwise on the 4-th loop the crash will occur.

Comment: I tested again,  the problem may be: it can not exit when it reach the end of file, although I used `IF (istat /= 0) EXIT` at the end of the do loop. I insert a `WRITE()"XX"` in the loop. the result is  ```$ ./read
 ENTER the file name with the data to be read: 
inp
 OPEN done 
 (XX 4 lines)
 OPEN done   
 (XX 4 lines)
 OPEN done 
 (XX 4 lines)  
 OPEN done 
 (XX 4 lines)  
 OPEN done 
At line 35 of file read.f95 (unit = 9, file = 'inp')
Fortran runtime error: End of file
```

Comment: I had tried to add `use iso_fortran_env` in the code and changed `IF (istat /= 0) EXIT` to  `if (stat == iostat_end) exit`, but the problem is still the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a test on the `IOSTAT` missing with the first executed `READ` in the loop. When the result is not OK the loop can be terminated e.g. change:

```
fileopen: IF (istat == 0) THEN
    input: DO
      !WRITE(*,*) "OPEN done " ! for testing
      READ(9,*)                ! <--when run, error is in this line
      READ(9,*)
```

in

```
fileopen: IF (istat == 0) THEN
    input: DO
      !WRITE(*,*) "OPEN done " ! for testing
      READ(9,*,IOSTAT=istat)
      IF (istat /=0) EXIT
      READ(9,*)
```

Comment: I test the `IOSTAT` with the first `READ`, then it works!